# Java Database API requiring no XML configuration

Tags: java, database, api

I am recently back in Javaland from Ruby and Activerecord and was wondering if there were any database solutions that do not require me to set up XML files to use them, and if possible supply any configuration in pure Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like ActiveRecords in Ruby, you might be interested in jOOQ (Java Object Oriented Querying, a database abstraction library that I wrote). jOOQ requires only little configuration for its source code generator. Your database schema is mapped 1:1 to Java classes, which can then be used in a fluent API very similar to SQL itself.

Also, jOOQ doesn't manage transactions, sessions, caches, etc like JPA or Hibernate might do. So there is no additional runtime configuration required.

http://www.jooq.org

Comment: I took a quick look. With JOOQ what happens to the autogenerated Java classes when the database schema changes?

Comment: You will have to re-generate those classes. If the change is incompatible (renaming of tables, columns, changing types of columns, etc), you will have compile-time errors. Ideally, the jOOQ source code generator is run at compile/build time.

Comment: Do you need to recompile if you only add fields?

Comment: Adding fields is what I'd consider a *compatible change*. Hence, you don't need to re-generate anything. Those fields will just not be selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Hibernate without using any XML via the [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) class (it doesn't *have* to read XML documents). It's easier to avoid the mapping of `.hbm.xml` files if you're using annotated classes and [AnnotationConfiguration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) instead.

See this for more details: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

Answer (score 2):

There are many. Though hibernate is the most famous one. It has annotation for most of the configuration and that too is not required, if you use naming strategies.

[http://www.hibernate.org/](http://www.hibernate.org)